# Can a "plain" php application use a laravel user table for authentication?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, hash, laravel-5.3

Currently I have a Laravel application with authentication. I'm wondering if I could have another PHP application (framework independent) that uses the same user table for authentication. I don't want to use Laravel again because it would be a over engineering.

My main concern is how the hashing of the password is done in Laravel. Can I configure the plain PHP application to hash passwords the same way? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Dive into Laravel sources and find how passwords are hashed.

Comment: what if you should had your plain php code redirect the request to your auth endpoints inside of Laravel and then let Laravel do the auth and return a response to initial php code that then proceeds as it should after successful authentication or throws an error back at client if unsuccessful.

Comment: @victor i hadn't thought about this! Sounds like it could work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a password hash (see the [`make()`](https://github.com/illuminate/hashing/blob/5.4/BcryptHasher.php#L26) method source code):

```
password_hash('somePassword555', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

And [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check password hash (see the [`check()`](https://github.com/illuminate/hashing/blob/5.4/BcryptHasher.php#L47) method source code):

```
password_verify('somePassword555', $hashedPasswordFromDB);
```

Comment: Thank you! Just tested these functions on some passwords already stored and they work!

Answer (score 1):

This is the file you want to check out
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php

And these are the functions they are using, `password_hash();` and `password_verify();`

```
function make($value, array $options = [])
    {
        $cost = isset($options['rounds']) ? $options['rounds'] : $this->rounds;
    $hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => $cost]);

    if ($hash === false) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Bcrypt hashing not supported.');
    }

    return $hash;
}

function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = [])
{
    if (strlen($hashedValue) === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return password_verify($value, $hashedValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This will help a lot! Was looking in the completely wrong place for these